# Pass data PHP Multidimentional Array to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I searched through this site for a solution but unfortunately, didn't worked at all so I've decided to ask you guys. Hope you help me out.

I have this PHP file that pushing values into an array.

**PHP FILE:**

```
$out_html = array();
$type1_ach = array(
    "title" => $ach_info[0], //Title1 is Value of $ach_info[0]
    "description" => $ach_info[1] //Description1 is Value of $ach_info[1]
);
array_push($out_html, $type1_ach);

$type5_ach = array(
    "title" => $ach_info[0], //Title2 is Value of $ach_info[0]
    "description" => $ach_info[1] //Description2 is Value of $ach_info[1]
);

array_push($out_html, $type5_ach);
```

and I echoed it using JSON since I'm passing it through jquery.

`echo json_encode($out_html);`

And here is my HTML File which should output the data that I passed from PHP File.

**HTML FILE:**

```
function test_pop() {
    var fb_id = "1**************"; //Facebook ID
    var v_id = "***********"; //Video ID

$.post('http://mysite.com/test.php', {fb_id: fb_id, v_id: v_id}, function(data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    var title = obj.title;
    var description = obj.description;
    var whole_ach = "You obtained " + title + "<br>" + description;
    console.log(whole_ach);

});
}
```

It outputs in console log the response is:

**You obtained undefined < br > undefined**

Then if I change the variables `var title = obj.title;` into `var title = obj.title[0];`
and `description = obj.description` into `description = obj.description[0]` it gives an output(response)

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

The desired output should be **You obtained Title1 < br > Description1** but unfortunately I can't seem to do it right.

Hope you guys help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be receiving an array of objects. So `data` is an array but you are treating it like an object.

Try looping over the array:

```
$.each(obj,function( index, item){    
   console.log( item.title);    
})
```

Or if you want to directly access a value from the main array:

```
console.log( obj[0].title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to update your JavaScript code:

```
function test_pop() {
    var fb_id = "1**************"; //Facebook ID
    var v_id = "***********"; //Video ID

$.post('http://mysite.com/test.php', {fb_id: fb_id, v_id: v_id}, function(data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    var title = obj[0].title;
    var description = obj[0].description;
    var whole_ach = "You obtained " + title + "\n" + description;
    console.log(whole_ach);

});
}
```

You need to specify the array index number:

```
    var title = obj[0].title;
    var description = obj[0].description;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it also worked but couldn't accept your answer, someone answered before you. Still thanks for the efforts that you did. :)